# I'm not sure how to delete a user using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to be able to delete a user if they choose to delete their account. I'm not sure how it's properly done. Here's the code for the delete function. I've looked at other StackOverflow solutions but I haven't been able to grasp the concept just yet. can anyone help?

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const User = require('../modelSchema/User')
const mongo = require('mongodb')

const signUp = (req, res) => {
    
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if(!errors.isEmpty()) return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array()})

    //new instance of user
   const user = new User({ 
    name: req.body.name, 
    email: req.body.email, 
    password: req.body.password })

    //save the user 
  user.save()
  .then(data => {
      res.json(data)
      res.send('User added successfully!')
      console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json(err)
  })

}

const deleteUser = (req, res) => {

    let id = req.params.id;
    User.get().createCollection('user', function ( col) {
     col.deleteOne({_id: new mongo.ObjectId(id)});
    });
    res.json({ success: id })
    res.send('User Deleted Successfully!')
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json(err)
    })
}

module.exports = { signUp, deleteUser }
```

here are the routes that I'm using

```
const express = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator')
const { signUp, deleteUser } = require('../controllers/users');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', [
    check('name', 'Please Enter your Name').not().isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please Enter your Email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Please Enter your Password').isLength({ minLength: 6})
], signUp)

router.delete('/delete/:id', deleteUser)

module.exports = router;
```

and here's my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: 'string', required: true},
    email: { type: 'string', required: true},
    password: { type: 'string', required: true},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)
```

Comment: Have you tried to `await` the results of your calls to the database?

Comment: no, i haven't attempted to do so. Im a beginner and am still learning my way around things.

Answer (score 0):

Update your delete function as below

```
const deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const user = await User.findByIdAndDelete(id);
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json("User not found");
  }
  res.status(200).json("User deleted successfully");
};
```

findByIdAndDelete takes an ObjectId of a user to be deleted. If the user exist, it'll delete the user and return user document, else return null;